# Why can I call multiple Option methods that consume self without error?

Tags: rust

```
let option: Option<&str> = None;
// -- unwrap --
let unwrap = panic::catch_unwind(|| option.unwrap());
assert!(unwrap.is_err());
let unwrap_or_default = option.unwrap_or_default();
assert!(unwrap_or_default == "");
let unwrap_or = option.unwrap_or("");
assert!(unwrap_or == "");
let unwrap_or_else = option.unwrap_or_else(|| "");
assert!(unwrap_or_else == "");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7a448371adf660ca5b7d088b041777c3)

The methods `Option::unwrap_xxx(self) -> T` all consume `self`, so why we can repeatedly call these methods without a compilation error? Isn't the `Option` moved?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Have you ever unwrapped your birthday present 5 times and then ended up with 5 presents? I think, the question wonders, why unwrap can be repeated, while the author thinks, there is some sort of move semantics to expect.

Comment: @RobinZigmond 
@BitTickler
isn't the variable `option` removed after calling unwrapxxx?

Comment: @PitaJ Now I understand, thank you very much for clarifying 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust has the `Copy` trait which is generally used on small values stored on the stack, like `i32`, `bool`, and references. If a type implements `Copy`, it will be *copied* instead of *moved*. Quoting [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy):

> If a type implements the `Copy` trait, a variable is still valid after assignment to another variable.

The same applies when passing the variable into a function. The variable will remain valid, as it is copied, not moved.

`Copy` exists mostly for ergonomics reasons (otherwise explicit `.clone()` would need to be used too often). And fittingly, [`Option<T>` implements `Copy` where `T` implements `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Copy).